# Кнопка удалить выдаёт ошибку, в чем может быт проблема C# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    DataTable data =  Class1.select(@" DELETE FROM rabotnik WHERE name=" + dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()); 
    data = Class1.select(@"SELECT * FROM rabotnik"); 
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data; 
    // ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

name и rabotnik, указаны правильно, в чем может быть проблема

Comment: вот вам удобно было бы отвечать на вопрос где код картинкой, а не текстом?

Comment: private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable data = Class1.select(@" DELETE FROM rabotnik WHERE name=" + dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            data = Class1.select(@"SELECT * FROM rabotnik");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

Comment: забыл указать, извиняюсь

Comment: Прямо в вопрос вставьте. Отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Если ответ верный, то Вы можете отметить его как правильный. См. справку: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке сказано, что MySQL не знает такой колонки: Aleksandr

Почему он мог так решить, ведь такую колонку в коде вы нигде не указываете?

Давайте внимательнее посмотрим на эту часть кода:

```
"DELETE FROM rabotnik WHERE name=" + dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

И скорее всего Вы выбрали в гриде запись Aleksandr

И составили следующий запрос:

```
DELETE FROM rabotnik WHERE name = Aleksandr;
```

Но вы забыли обернуть имя в кавычки, как строковый литерал.
В итоге MySQL пытается найти все записи где колонка `name` равна колонке `Aleksandr`, чтобы удалить их.
Не находит такую колонку, о чем и сообщает вам в ошибке

**Решение:**
Просто оберните имя в кавычки

```
String name = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
String sql = String.Format("DELETE FROM rabotnik WHERE name='{0}'", name);
```